# InvalidClassException and serialization issues

Tags: serialization, ioexception

So i have an exercise given from my lecturer to build a registration system.
My job is to test the program. My friends gave me the source code, but i cant seem to get it running, although one of my friend can open it without any problems

Here is the error message

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: javax.swing.JComponent; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -3424753864000836906, local class serialVersionUID = 3742318830738515599
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:621)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:199)
at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:80)
at gui.MainWindow.initComponents(MainWindow.java:208)
at gui.MainWindow.<init>(MainWindow.java:34)
at srs.Driver.main(Driver.java:17)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Component must be non-null
at javax.swing.GroupLayout$ComponentSpring.<init>(GroupLayout.java:2953)
at javax.swing.GroupLayout$ComponentSpring.<init>(GroupLayout.java:2933)
at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.addComponent(GroupLayout.java:1524)
at javax.swing.GroupLayout$ParallelGroup.addComponent(GroupLayout.java:2484)
at javax.swing.GroupLayout$ParallelGroup.addComponent(GroupLayout.java:2454)
at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.addComponent(GroupLayout.java:1505)
at javax.swing.GroupLayout$ParallelGroup.addComponent(GroupLayout.java:2476)
at gui.MainWindow.initComponents(MainWindow.java:1680)
at gui.MainWindow.<init>(MainWindow.java:34)
at srs.Driver.main(Driver.java:17)
```

Java Result: 1

In one of the package i have this class called "**MainWindow.java**", and "**MainWindow_creditsField2.ser**". This package is for GUI purposes.

I am assuming the error has something to do with the **.ser** file. When I asked my friend what that file is, he did not know what that file is, and said that it's
automatically generated

When I clicked on 3 of the last errors,

- Driver tells me the line MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
- MainWindow tells me line initComponents();

I think that is all the leads I can give you

Comment: You're running a different version of Java from your friend.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the serialization . [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10378907/3096792) is the link where it is described nicely why it occurs. Go through [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) thoroughly to understand how that field is used to make sure the serialized version and what the JVM wants to create from the serialized object are the same.