# InvalidClassException when having ArrayList in constructor arguments

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist

When I write an object with an ArrayList in the constructor's arguments (even if I do nothing with it) to a file and read it back, it will throw an InvalidClassException and say the serialVersionUID for the objects don't match, however taking it out from the constructor will allow it to behave normally again. What could be causing this error?

This constructor would work fine

```
public Post(String poster, String postName, int imageWidth, int imageHeight){
    this.poster = poster;
    this.postID = generateID();
    this.postName = postName;
    this.imageWidth = imageWidth;
    this.imageHeight = imageHeight;
}
```

however this one would throw an error

```
public Post(String poster, String postName, ArrayList keys, int imageWidth, int imageHeight){
    this.poster = poster;
    this.postID = generateID();
    this.postName = postName;
    this.imageWidth = imageWidth;
    this.imageHeight = imageHeight;
}
```

The way I'm saving it to a file is just with an ObjectOutputStream with a FileOutputStream as the parameter, and reading it with an ObjectInputStream with a FileInputStream

Here's the stack trace

```
11-27 15:34:50  java.io.InvalidClassException: net.gladiatorlife.aoit.test.Post; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -4349899324072111291, local class serialVersionUID = 5190858650678115513
11-27 15:34:50      at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:617)
11-27 15:34:50      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1622)
11-27 15:34:50      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
11-27 15:34:50      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
11-27 15:34:50      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
11-27 15:34:50      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
11-27 15:34:50      at net.gladiatorlife.aoit.test.util.FileUtil.readFromFile(FileUtil.java:48)
11-27 15:34:50      at net.gladiatorlife.aoit.test.order.request.LatestOrder.handle(LatestOrder.java:45)
11-27 15:34:50      at net.gladiatorlife.aoit.test.Connection$1.run(Connection.java:121)
11-27 15:34:50      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**EDIT**
Problem solved by manually setting the serializable id to -4349899324072111291L

Comment: Can you put some code here?try to help you?

Comment: Right, sorry. There you go.

Comment: Could you please post your stack trace?

Comment: Please add the exception which you have in the console

Comment: There you go, added it.

Comment: Define a member in the class concerned : private static long serialVersionUID = 5190858650678115513L; i think that will resolve the problem

Comment: Didn't work. It still gave the same error (numbers were the same as well). Perhaps it's a problem with the ArrayList itself and serialization?

Comment: ok. so plz refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335813/java-serialization-java-io-invalidclassexception-local-class-incompatible

Comment: You may find your solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378855/java-io-invalidclassexception-local-class-incompatible

Comment: Solved it by using -4349899324072111291 rather than 5190858650678115513