# Error With ManyToMany relation in Spring project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring project and i have two entitys. I make ManyToMany relation between them. My entitys are Event and User. Here is what error i get:

```
    java.io.InvalidClassException: com.example.app.entity.User; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -5953916207201729314, local class serialVersionUID = -8613364070144931169
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:687) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1876) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1745) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2033) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:427) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:225) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:139) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:28) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:261) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:247) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:333) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2854) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1747) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1673) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1562) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:732) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:991) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:949) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2692) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2675) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2507) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2502) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:392) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1489) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1445) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:307) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:74) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:377) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:629) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:593) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy97.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.example.app.Controllers.EventsController.getEventsAndPeoplePage(EventsController.java:58) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_161]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_161]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]
```

here is my User Entity:

```
    package com.example.app.entity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table (name = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

private String username;
private String password;
private String email;
private boolean isAccountNonExpired;
private boolean isAccountNonLocked;
private boolean isCredentialsNonExpired;
private boolean isEnabled;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name = "users_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<Role> authorities = new HashSet<Role>();

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "players")
private Set<Event> events = new HashSet<>();

public Set<Event> getEvents() {
    return events;
}

public void setEvents(Set<Event> events) {
    this.events = events;
}

@Override
public Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
    return authorities;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return isAccountNonExpired;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return isAccountNonLocked;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return isCredentialsNonExpired;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return isEnabled;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public void setAccountNonExpired(boolean accountNonExpired) {
    isAccountNonExpired = accountNonExpired;
}

public void setAccountNonLocked(boolean accountNonLocked) {
    isAccountNonLocked = accountNonLocked;
}

public void setCredentialsNonExpired(boolean credentialsNonExpired) {
    isCredentialsNonExpired = credentialsNonExpired;
}

public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    isEnabled = enabled;
}

public void setAuthorities(Set<Role> authorities) {
    this.authorities = authorities;
}
}
```

and here is my Event Entity:

```
    package com.example.app.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table (name = "events")
public class Event {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

private String name;
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "games_at_event", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
@Column(name = "games")
private List<String> games = new ArrayList<>();

@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinTable(name = "event_users",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "event_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")})
private Set<User> players = new HashSet<>();

private double latitude;
private double longitude;
private String description;
private String date;
private User owner;
private String gamesToParse;
private String usersToParse;


public String getGamesToParse() {
    return gamesToParse;
}

public void setGamesToParse(String gamesToParse) {
    this.gamesToParse = gamesToParse;
}

public String getUsersToParse() {
    return usersToParse;
}

public void setUsersToParse(String usersToParse) {
    this.usersToParse = usersToParse;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public User getOwner(){
    return owner;
}
public void setOwner(User owner){
    this.owner = owner;
}

public String getDescription(){
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description){
    this.description = description;
}

public double getLatitude(){
    return latitude;
}
public void setLatitude(double latitude){
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public double getLongitude(){
    return longitude;
}
public void setLongitude( double longitude){
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}
public void setName( String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public List<String> getGames() {
    return games;
}

public void setGames(List<String> games) {
    this.games = games;
}

public void setGames(String gamesData) {
    String[] array = gamesData.split(",");
    for (String g:array) {
        this.games.add(g);
    }
}

public Set<User> getPlayers() {
    return players;
}

public void setPlayers(String playersData) {
    String[] array = playersData.split(",");
    for (String p:array) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail(p);
        this.players.add(user);
    }
}

}
```

I don't know why i got this error everything seems right. I someone wants my RegistrationModel i will edit the question and will add it.

Answer (score 0):

This is serialization error, you can try using explicit serialVersionUID on the User class. 
If you want more details you can take a look at javadocs on java.io.Serializable interface and this has been answered here as well 
[java.io.InvalidClassException: local class incompatible:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378855/java-io-invalidclassexception-local-class-incompatible)