# Parent/Child Serialization local class incompatible Exception

Tags: java

I'm getting a serialization compatibility error from the below two classes.  Only the parent class, CommericalCustomer implements serialization. What is the proper way to use the Serializable Interface when having a parent/child relation as I have below?

```
public class CachedCommercialCustomers extends CommercialCustomer {


}

public class CommercialCustomer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

**Exception:**

```
[#|2013-01-02T05:01:02.553-0800|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|com.hazelcast.nio.AbstractSerializer|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|spot.api.model.vo.backoffice.CachedCommercialCustomers; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -2672531984245897526, local class serialVersionUID = -743225273062282831
java.io.InvalidClassException: com.sample.CachedCommercialCustomers; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -2672531984245897526, local class serialVersionUID = -743225273062282831
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:579)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1600)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1513)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1749)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1346)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readUnshared(ObjectInputStream.java:458)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.DefaultSerializer$ObjectSerializer.readNormal(DefaultSerializer.java:383)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.DefaultSerializer$ObjectSerializer.read(DefaultSerializer.java:353)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.DefaultSerializer.read(DefaultSerializer.java:134)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.CustomSerializerAdapter.read(CustomSerializerAdapter.java:33)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.AbstractSerializer.toObject(AbstractSerializer.java:116)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.AbstractSerializer.toObject(AbstractSerializer.java:146)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.Serializer.readObject(Serializer.java:72)
        at com.hazelcast.impl.ThreadContext.toObject(ThreadContext.java:103)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.IOUtil.toObject(IOUtil.java:149)
        at com.hazelcast.impl.BaseManager$RequestBasedCall.getResultAsObject(BaseManager.java:384)
        at com.hazelcast.impl.BaseManager$ResponseQueueCall.getResultAsObject(BaseManager.java:455)
        at com.hazelcast.impl.BaseManager$RequestBasedCall.getResultAsObject(BaseManager.java:368)
        at com.hazelcast.impl.BaseManager$ResponseQueueCall.getResultAsObject(BaseManager.java:455)
```

Comment: Well it looks like the problem is that your `CachedCommercialCustomers` class has changed since you serialized the value. Personally I'd avoid Java's default binary serialization entirely...

Comment: any class extending CommercialCustomer is serializable.

Comment: add private static final long serialVersionUID = -2672531984245897526L; to CachedCommercialCustomers see what happens.

Comment: @BevynQ - I get a java.io.InvalidClassException: local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -743225273062282831, local class serialVersionUID = -2672531984245897526

Comment: @c 12 - the class definition has changed and you probably have the two different versions in the store you are accessing, you will need to flush the store. You should think about stating from scratch if you were intending CachedCommercialCustomers not to be serialized. I would suggest making it a Holder or Wrapper class instead of extending CommericialCustomer.

Comment: @BevynQ - shouldn't a redeploy and bounce of the web server flush the store?

Comment: @c 12 - probably where is hazelcast reading things from if it is a database or something like that you will need to remove the objects from it.

Comment: BevynQ can you post your last comment as a answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you don't specify a `serialVersionId` for your sub class - so java will generate one for you instead. A simple recompilation might change this value if you change the java source file. See the [spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/class.html).

The fact that the I'd changes when the code changes is a good thing, but in some cases it will cause you some grief :)

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335813/java-serialization-java-io-invalidclassexception-local-class-incompatible) for more information and how to "fix" the problem if necessary.