# java.lang.InternalError: com.sun.msv.grammar.BinaryExp; local class incompatible

Tags: java, websphere

I have deployed an enterprise application (ear) to a WebSphere Application Server (6.1) which is hosted on an UNIX Server and I am was able to run the application successfully.

The same enterprise application when deployed to a WebSphere Application Server (6.1) which is hosted on a Windows 7 machine, results in the following issue:

com.sun.msv.grammar.BinaryExp class is part of the jar file jax-libs.jar and this is one of the utility jars that is used by my application.

I really appreciate if someone can help me with this

The stack trace is shown below:

```
[12/3/13 15:38:55:679 PST] 00000021 ServletWrappe E   SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception thrown in one of the service methods of the servlet: HttpControllerServlet. Exception thrown : java.lang.InternalError: com.sun.msv.grammar.BinaryExp; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -6949881705297518665, local class serialVersionUID = 1
    at com.sun.xml.bind.validator.SchemaDeserializer.deserialize(SchemaDeserializer.java:64)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.validator.SchemaDeserializer.deserialize(SchemaDeserializer.java:41)
    at org.kp.eci.model.xml.impl.UserPreferenceTypeImpl.<clinit>(UserPreferenceTypeImpl.java:26)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:192)
    at org.kp.eci.model.xml.impl.UserPreferenceTypeImpl$MySpecialtyAreasTypeImpl.<clinit>(UserPreferenceTypeImpl.java:696)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:192)
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:130)
    at org.kp.eci.model.xml.ObjectFactory.class$(ObjectFactory.java:18)
    at org.kp.eci.model.xml.ObjectFactory.<clinit>(ObjectFactory.java:18)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:192)
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:163)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.GrammarInfoFacade.createGrammarInfoFacade(GrammarInfoFacade.java:110)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.DefaultJAXBContextImpl.<init>(DefaultJAXBContextImpl.java:70)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:615)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:142)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:259)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:372)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:337)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:244)
    at org.kp.eci.model.UserPreference.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.kp.eci.da.UserPreferenceDA.getUserPreference(Unknown Source)
    at org.kp.eci.eventhandler.LoginHandler.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.kp.eci.mvc.model.AbstractStateMachine.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.kp.eci.mvc.control.HttpRequestProcessor.processRequest(Unknown Source)
    at org.kp.eci.mvc.control.HttpControllerServlet.doGet(Unknown Source)
    at org.kp.eci.mvc.control.HttpControllerServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:763)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:989)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:501)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:464)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3252)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:264)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:811)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1439)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:112)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:383)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:102)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1815)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:195)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:743)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:873)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1469)
```

Comment: Looking at your error message, i think this is a big clue - "local class incompatible". After that, our best friend Google suggests that we try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335813/java-serialization-java-io-invalidclassexception-local-class-incompatible

Comment: or this - http://www.mkyong.com/java-best-practices/understand-the-serialversionuid/

Comment: Tell us all if it helped.

Comment: thanks for your reply.unfortunately the solution did help me to solve the problem.i tried to build and deploy the application with new jar(jaxb-libs-1.5.jar) which i have downloaded from findjar.com. still i am facing the same error. As my application is using the above jar as utility jar I could not able to do beyond that.