# Can't read '.dat' files from folder

Tags: java, file

I am trying to read multiple '.dat' files one by one inside a specific folder. below is my code

```
public void viewEngingeer() throws Exception
    {
        File f = new File("Users");
        ArrayList<String> usersList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(f.list()));

    int index=0;
    while (index < usersList.size()) { 
    User newUser=new User();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("Users/"+usersList.get(index));
    ObjectInputStream ois =  new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    newUser = (User) ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    System.out.println(newUser.getUsername());     
    index++;
    }

 }
```

but I am getting error on running

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.InvalidClassException: oodj.User; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -7994693857260427394, local class serialVersionUID = 4996613179002222501
```

---

any ideas? Thank you

Comment: What line does the error occur?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java serialization - java.io.InvalidClassException local class incompatible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335813/java-serialization-java-io-invalidclassexception-local-class-incompatible)

Comment: Looks like the class wich is stored in file is not the same as your `User` class. Are you sure that the class in dat file is a user object?

Comment: jens, yes it is the same.
actually now I am getting what I want but still error exists after result

this is output:

Shaher
Sam
Monir
Omar
Phaisal
Exception in thread "main" java.io.InvalidClassException: oodj.User; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 4996613179002222501, local class serialVersionUID = -7994693857260427394
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
 at oodj.test.viewEngingeer(test.java:31)
 at oodj.OODJ.main(OODJ.java:14)
Java Result: 1

Comment: Dmitry Tsechoev Thank you worked after I removed all old files and created new ones after adding static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deserialization is impossible. Java can not restore object. You need add something like this:

```
 static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;
```

in your class *User* and make *User* implements *Serializable*.

See more here: [Serializabe](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)

Comment: Please, argument your "minus".